# ssh slow to prompt for password (CentOS 6.10)

Tags: centos

$ ssh user@host
user@host's password: <----- Takes 30-50 seconds to prompt for password

If i use debug

$ ssh -vvv user@host
.
.
.
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSH_7.4 <--- Here is where is stuck for 30-50 seconds

waiting for line below, but after that is ok.
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3

Comment: is the server attempting DNS lookups? I recall CentOS enabling those by default

Comment: Does adding `UseDNS no` to your sshd_config and restarting the ssh service, solves the problem?